# MDT 2013 Update 1 breaks USMT?

Tags: windows, migration, sccm, mdt

After upgrading from MDT 2012 to 2013 Update 1 (6.3.8298), USMT seems broken. Whether using the new XML files or the old ones we used in 2012, it does not migrate the user wallpaper or IE homepage when selecting to move the user data from the task sequence from WinPE. I've been searching for days but can't find other people online with this issue. I've even created a brand new deployment share from scratch and it's the same issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have custom MigApp, MigUser, etc .xml files?  When you do a fresh install of MDT, you're going to end up with a fresh copy of all of these USMT files as well.

To get the old USMT behavior back, just find your old USMT files and replace them within the Deployment Share\USMT folder.

Comment: That is not the issue, as fresh USMT xml files should by default migrate the wallpaper. In addition, this new version of MDT overrides the xml files each time you update the deployment share. However, I do have custom files that I'm calling in CustomSettings.ini, but with them it's still broken.

I did find a post on Technet somewhere that says USMT10 isn't compatible with Windows 7, and the solution is to use USMT5. So no solution so far unfortunately.

Comment: I'll take a look at the USMT files and see if I can find the errors. There was a similar problem when USMT 4 shipped, that office wouldn't be migrated. That was caused by misnamed xml nodes in the default USMT field that shipped with that release.for example, what should have been called migrateoffice2012to2012 was called upgrade2012to2012, causing the USMT role to never evaluate.